# jQuery's $.fn.myFunction is listed but undefined when checking $.isFunction

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

jQuery's $.fn shows myFunction is listed as a function when I do

```
console.log($.fn)
```

however when I do:

```
console.log($.fn.myFunction)
```

it returns undefined

I have the following code for debugging purposes:

```
console.log($.fn);
//returns a list of functions with myFunction correctly listed as one
console.log($.fn.myFunction);
//returns undefined
console.log($.fn.contextmenu);
//correctly returns the function (I believe this is a generic jQuery function)
console.log($.fn.myFunction);
//returns undefined
console.log($.isFunction($.fn.myFunction));
//returns false
console.log($.isFunction($.myFunction));
//returns false
```

Comment: If you are calling `$.fn.myFunction` before your plugin is loaded, it will be undefined. Remember that the console lazy loads so the `$.fn` line may have data that is loaded after you call it.

Comment: ah I didn't know that, I do have this code at the end of my scripts list, I probably had to wait until the page is loaded. EDIT: that was it, I just forgot to wait with my checks until the page was loaded. I didn't think of this since I saw it in the $.fn due to lazy loading. Thanks.